# How can I install 'restricted-extras' offline?

Tags: package-management

I currently don't have internet access in the house which means I have to go the cafe after a fresh 11.04 install, can anyone provide a link where I can get a .deb package (amd64)  of `ubuntu-restricted-extras` for 11.04?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install software offline?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline)

Comment: As others have stated, this is a metapackage, meaning it fetches about a dozen dependant packages. If you give us some idea of which component of restricted-extras you'd like to install (Flash? MP3 playback?), however, someone could provide a link to the individual packages.

Comment: Since this is a metapackage, and more importantly because *some of the packages installed as dependencies of `ubuntu-restricted-extras` **themselves** don't provide the actual software, but rather contain scripts to download it*, this is *not* a duplicate of [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Downloading the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package itself wont help you much. It is actually a "meta-package", ie, a package with no "real" content, but with a list of dependencies. Thats why its size is so small.

When you try to install it, it checks the dependencies and downloads and installs them. And those are a few tens of megabytes.

So, if you want a complete offline install, i suggest this:

- Go to any computer with internet, and use a Live CD/USB Ubuntu session. (so you have a clean OS with no extra package installed)
- Open Synaptics (Administration -> Package Manager), use the Quick Search for `ubuntu-restricted-extras`
- In the list, double-click it. On the dialog window, click Mark.

[image]

- Click Apply.
- It will show a window of all the packages that must be installed. **Those** are the ones you need to download and install in your offline machine.

[image]

- Either [download them manually](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), or check the "Download Package Files Only" checkbox. The DEBs will be downloaded to `/var/cache/apt/archives`
- You can also use `File -> Generate Package download script` option. Create a folder for the script, save it, then run it. All DEBs will be downloaded to that folder. Copy the whole folder to a USB/DVD, then use `File -> Add downloaded packages` option in the offline computer.

And, VERY important: both the offline and online computers must have the SAME architecture. (meaning 32/64 bits, OS, etc). So the package downloaded in one will be the correct one for the other.

Comment: There's an issue that won't be resolved by this solution: [flashplugin-installer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/flashplugin-installer) and [ttf-mscorefonts-installer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/ttf-mscorefonts-installer) both need Internet access during installation, even after their respective package files have been downloaded. This is to get around stupid legal restrictions which don't allow the Flash plug-in and the Microsoft fonts to be redistributed repackaged, even though there are free of charge. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: @Flimm - If the internet is required *at install time*, there's no .DEB solution for his problem. Only unpacking-editing-repacking would do it. (thats not illegal, as you wont *redistribute* the new package, just install it yourself.). Anyway, 100% offline software install and maintance in Linux world is a baaaaaaad ideia in the first place. Its an bad habi... err, "inheritance" from Windows that i look forward to see gone soon. Its SO much better when the OS picks the right pagkages, based on dependeicies, architecture, etc, and install all automaticaly...

Comment: I've found a way to resolve this. It's a bit complicated so I've posted the solution as a separate question and answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/46664/how-can-i-install-flashplugin-installer-and-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-without/46668#46668

Answer (score 4):

haha,, in indonesia which have slow connection, that's first thing that we do.Just download from 
[here](http://www.mediafire.com/?pbbd5t8iuj9bi0y)

and also ,if you want to install some apps from repository ,and you don't have connection but your friend or someone does, just [go here](http://apt-web.dahsy.at) type what you want to download, and the link appears with all dependencies

Answer (score 2):

If you have an internet connection on another computer (or you could always try a library), you could always download the required gstreamer .deb packages and put them on a flash drive. Then plug the flash drive into your internet-less computer and install.

Comment: It is a metapackage ,so direct copying .deb is not enough to do it

Comment: @tachyons Ah, I completely forgot about that. I've fixed the post.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have an Internet connection somewhere that you can utilize, but just not on the Ubuntu machine.

Try Apt-Offline:
http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT

The article about restricted formats in the community documentation might help you find what you need:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

I have never tried, apt-offline, but when my Ubuntu machine was without Internet connection I used a workaround like the following one to download the packages somewhere else: http://ershadk.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/how-to-download-deb-packages-for-offline-installation-2/

Answer (score 1):

Try and run `sudo aptitude download ubuntu-restricted-extras` on another Ubuntu 11.04 system. It should download a .deb package including all of the needed depencies.
Alternatively, you can also use APTonCD.

Comment: See my comment to [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/45208/how-can-i-install-restricted-extras-offline/45298#45298).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the offline installer made by hacktolive.org