# How can I install `flashplugin-installer` and `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` without an Internet connection?

Tags: software-installation

Is there a way to download the Flash plug-in and the Microsoft fonts on one computer, and install them on another offline computer?

Simply downloading the `flashplugin-installer` and `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` packages isn't enough, as both these packages require Internet connections during their installation.

According to `flashplugin-installer`'s description:

> WARNING: Installing this Ubuntu package causes the Adobe Flash Player plugin to be downloaded from www.adobe.com. The distribution license of the Adobe Flash Player plugin is available at www.adobe.com. Installing this Ubuntu package implies that you have accepted the terms of that license.

And `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` has a similar warning:

> You will need an Internet connection to download these fonts if you don't already have them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need a computer of the same architecture as the offline computer. This computer needs to be the same computer architecture as the offline computer (i.e: i386 32-bit or i686 64-bit). It needs to be running the same release of Ubuntu as the offline computer.

### On the online computer:

---

### Download the needed packages:

1. Create a directory in your home folder named `files-downloaded`.
2. On the online computer, launch Synaptic. Under Ubuntu 11.04, this easily done by pressing the <kbd>windows</kbd> button, and then typing `synaptic package manager`.
3. Find the package named `flashplugin-installer`, right-click on it and mark it for installation. If it is already installed, mark it for re-installation. [image: Marking flashplugin-installer for installation]
4. If a dialog window asks you to install `libnspr4-0d`, click Mark. If this dialog doesn't appear, you will need to find `libnspr4-0d` yourself and mark it for re-installation.
5. Find the package named `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, right-click on it and mark it for installation. If it is already installed, mark it for re-installation.
6. If a dialog window asks you to install `cabextract`, click Mark. If this dialog doesn't appear, you will need to find `cabextract` yourself and mark it for re-installation.
7. Find the package named `debconf-utils` and mark it for installation or re-installation as necessary. This package is required later on to set the offline location of the additional files we are going to download.
8. Click `File`->`Generate package download script`, and save the script under the `files-download` directory with the name `download-packages`. [image: Generating package download script]
9. Open a terminal by pressing the <kbd>windows</kbd> key and typing `terminal`.
10. Type the following. This will download all the required .deb files to the `files-downloaded` folder.

    ```
    cd ~/files-downloaded
    sudo chown username:username download-packages
    chmod +x download-packages
    ./download-packages
    ```

### Download the fonts:

1. Save the following code as `files-downloaded/download-fonts`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   set -e

   FONTS='andale32.exe arial32.exe arialb32.exe comic32.exe courie32.exe 
   georgi32.exe impact32.exe times32.exe trebuc32.exe verdan32.exe webdin32.exe'

   URLROOTS="http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/
       http://switch.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/corefonts/
       http://mesh.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/corefonts/
       http://dfn.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/corefonts/
       http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/corefonts/
       http://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/corefonts/
       http://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/corefonts/
       http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/corefonts/
       http://internode.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/corefonts/
       http://voxel.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/corefonts/
       http://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/corefonts/
       http://internap.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/corefonts/"

   for font in $FONTS
   do
       for website in $URLROOTS
       do
           if ! wget -c ${website}${font} ; then
               continue 1;
           fi
           break
       done
   done

   echo Done
   ```
2. Open a terminal and type the following:

   ```
   cd ~/files-downloaded
   chmod +x download-fonts
   ./download-fonts
   ```

### Download the Flash plugin tarball:

1. Save the following code as `files-downloaded/download-flash`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   set -e

   # Ensure that the flash plugin is installed and the latest version:
   sudo apt-get install -y flashplugin-installer

   FLASH_VERSION_LINE=$(grep -m 1 ^FLASH_VERSION= /var/lib/dpkg/info/flashplugin-installer.postinst)

   eval $FLASH_VERSION_LINE

   echo Flash version: "$FLASH_VERSION"

   FILENAME=adobe-flashplugin_${FLASH_VERSION}.orig.tar.gz
   PARTNER_URL=http://archive.canonical.com/pool/partner/a/adobe-flashplugin/$FILENAME


   wget -c "$PARTNER_URL"

   echo Done
   ```
2. Open a terminal and type the following:

   ```
   cd ~/files-downloaded
   chmod +x download-flash
   ./download-flash
   ```

### Transfer:

Now copy the folder named `files-downloaded` to a USB stick or use your favourite file synchronising service. This folder should have 11 .exe files, one .tar.gz file, five .deb files and three scripts.

### On the offline computer:

---

1. Copy the folder named `files-downloaded` to your home directory.
2. Run the following in a terminal:

   ```
   cd ~/files-downloaded
   sudo dpkg -i debconf-utils_*.deb cabextract_*.deb libnspr4-0d_*.deb

   echo flashplugin-installer flashplugin-installer/local string ~/files-downloaded/ | sudo debconf-set-selections
   echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/dldir string ~/files-downloaded/ | sudo debconf-set-selections

   sudo dpkg -i flashplugin-installer_*.deb
   sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_*.deb

   echo flashplugin-installer flashplugin-installer/local string | sudo debconf-set-selections
   echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/dldir string | sudo debconf-set-selections
   ```
3. You're done! That was a lot more complicated than it should have been, but sadly both Adobe and Microsoft restrict the distribution of Flash and their fonts respectively. This is the only legal way to get round their strict licensing.

---

Just add if you are bugged with install of flashplugin-installer failing due to dependency update-notifier-common you can use the below steps to reinstall update-notifier-common:

Delete the files under `/usr/share/package-data-downloads`:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/share/package-data-downloads/*
```

Install update-notifier-common again:

```
sudo apt-get install update-notifier-common
```

This should now complete without attempting to download flash or fonts
    Rerun the script in the last part it should just work