# How do I get the required mp3 and mp4 codecs without an internet connection?

Tags: music, mp3, mp4, ubuntu-restricted-extras

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install 'restricted-extras' offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45208/how-can-i-install-restricted-extras-offline)

I use Ubuntu 11.10 without the Internet and I want to play the mp3 songs and mp4 movies. How can I do this?