# I want to play mp3 in rythmbox but it says python v2 plugins requires mpeg-1 layer mp3 decoder but i dont have internet on that computer,

Tags: installation, plugins, mp3, offline

Because  i use internet from usb device which supports only on windows, and when I downloaded offline files from packages.ubuntu.com and linuxappsfinder.com and tried to install them in ubuntu, i just double clicked on such file(whose format extension was .deb), then it opened in ubuntu software center but said, dependency is not supported, 
How can i install softwares and plugins or codecs in ubuntu, without internet?

I tried to make file through terminal using zipped files, (tar.bz2), but said something xml not found.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will tell you how to install the restricted extras needed to play mp3 files offline https://askubuntu.com/a/45298/71679 this [How can I update Ubuntu offline without using Synaptic or Keryx?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127923/how-can-i-update-ubuntu-offline-without-using-synaptic-or-keryx/165349#165349) will give even more information about updating offline

Lastly i have used many usb modems which were made for windows which all worked flawlessly in ubuntu.In fact simply plugging it in ubuntu recognised it and gave prompts to install.did you try?