# How to install Third party softwares from Ubuntu Installation CD after installation?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I accidentally unchecked the option to install third party proprietary softwares like mp3 codec during the installation of ubuntu.
Now I want to install them again. Is there any way to installing it from the CD instead of downloading the whole restricted extras package.
I am from a remote village with only 128 kbps dialup modem.

Comment: Excuse me @Mitch, the post you suggested does not describe how to install the packages later from cd, without downloading from Internet.

Comment: Sorry, Take a look at this [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/45208/how-can-i-install-restricted-extras-offline), it will show how to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe that when you check the option to install third part software, it downloads it from the internet, not from the CD. I'll keep looking :)

Comment: Thanks @SimplySimon, for the point. Is there any way to just download mp3,mp4 and avi decoders only from the package.. without flash player and other mess?

Comment: I checked your post @Mitch. But it still needs broadband internet. I am sorry. But I dont have any option to download the 106 MB package :(

Comment: If you have access to a system with high speed Internet, you can download the [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), and then install it on your machine.

Comment: I got the only packages for playing MP3's. It was only 1.2 MB. When I opened an MP3 in Movie Player, it asked me whether to find suitable decoder. I agreed and it brought me this plugin.

Comment: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-plugins-ugly/gst-plugins-ugly-1.0.7.tar.xz could be what you are looking for (826.7 kB).