# Ubuntu with all audio drivers

Tags: drivers, sound

Is there an ubuntu that comes pre-installed with all audio drivers considering that I dont have access to the internet that much

Comment: Normally the Ubuntu installation media includes all audio drivers, so if there is an audio hardware driver or codec that is missing in your Ubuntu you should include information about what in particular you need in your question.

Comment: probably you need this, [Ubuntu Restricted Extras](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/) and this, [How can I install 'restricted-extras' offline?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/45208/how-can-i-install-restricted-extras-offline)

Comment: @ShaharilAhmad No, this package contains no drivers.

Comment: @LiveWireBT Ubuntu already came with default driver in it's kernel. Mostly it will detect all drivers needed. May be what it need is codec to play audio file. More info would be helpful, though.

Comment: @ShaharilAhmad I know that. You should have written your first comment to point out that this might not be a driver issue but a codec issue and installing restricted extras meta packages might help.